# Can not connect glassfish server using mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to use MySQL query browser to perform some queries. For this reason I have installed MySQL workbench. Now I tried to get connected to my glassfish server using [this tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-admin.html)

In step 1 (specify Host Machine): I have selected *Remote Hoste* and entered the url I can see in glasfish Server *Additional Properties* `jdbc:mysql://....`

In step 2: I enter the username and password I also found in glassfish server *additional properties*. When I click on *next*, get the following error:

> ```
> Could not connect to MySQL server:  Unknown MySQL server host
>  jdbc:mysql://...
> ```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the exact JDBC URI you entered?

Comment: Is the MySQL server on the WAN and doesn't accept connections from the outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*emphasized text*I have resolved the Problem by deleting jdbc:mysql:// and writing only the uri without the schema.